# MaterializeCSS - Dynamically adding 'active' class to selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

I'm using localstorage to remember users responses on my selector, and I'd like the `active` selector to be added to an `li` dynamically.

I've gone with this route, but it doesn't seem to be working for me... Am I missing something or do I need to be doing something else? I'd really appreciate the advice.

```
    function loadResponses() {

            $(".selectFeed .dropdown-content li:nth-child("+activeIndex+")").addClass('active');
            $('select').material_select();

    }
```

Using the above code doesn't seem to work. `activeIndex` is the value that is being stored in the localstorage... Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Has `activeIndex` any value? What does `console.log(activeIndex)` say (inside the function)?

Comment: Also, does it work when you put an arbitrary index in there?

Comment: `activeIndex` does have a value. If I put an arbitrary index in there nothing happens. The same as with `activeIndex`.

Comment: Make sure the rest of your selector is correct. You can do that by console.log($(...)) - it should show something other than an empty array.

Comment: `console.log($('.selectFeed .dropdown-conetent li'));` returns `m.fn.init[0]`.. not sure if that is what you meant...

Comment: It is. Try adding the class to it and see what happens. $('.selectFeed .dropdown-conetent li').addClass(...)

Comment: Hmm strangely no class was added...

Comment: Are you sure about that? try console.log($('.selectFeed .dropdown-conetent li.active'));  later